# jquery why toggle autohides in mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I need to add kind of popup with jquery and toogle or slidetoogle

I have a simple example which works fine. When I click on the link, popup appears, doubleclick outside of popup - it disappears

But when I add such code to MVC view - when I click on the link popup slides fine and immediately slides out.

Why it can't stop? Why auto hides?

```
$("#btnSendEmail").click(function () {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'right', easing: 'swing' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 1000;

    $(".popup").toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$("#btnSendEmail").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ..
});
```

Comment: no luck, i think something with environment, not with the code snippet, i tried simple juery example from the api.jquery.com - the same

Comment: Then probably mvc is adding its own `.js` files which are mixing it up with ur own applied `.js`

Comment: did you tried increasing the duration? just try some big value.

Comment: I replaced $("#btnSendEmail").click(function with onclick="ToggleSendForm()" and problem dissappeared. It now stops after slides in :) I think question is closed

Comment: Just as an doubt...do you included `mvc` btn without any `id` but only with `name`?

Comment: Was just trying to do something like your code have a look at the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B3j8e/